# Error with system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()

Tags: apex, class

I am not able to save below line of code in my class and I am not sure where am I going wrong.

```
<a href = "system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/'+app.Main_Offer_Name__c"> Click Here</a>
```

Erros says 'Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments'.
Can someone please help me out with this one.

Also which base URL does system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() provide, classic or lightning?

Edit:
Whole line of code for better understanding:

```
String htmlBody = '<b>Notification:</b></br></br>The Offer has been Approved at Stage'+app.Stage__c+'</br></br><b>Main-Offer Name: </b>'+app.Main_Offer_Name__r.Name+ '</br></br><b>Offer Link: </b><a href = "system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/'+app.Main_Offer_Name__c"> Click Here</a></br></br>';
```

Comment: Not sure where are you writing that code. Is it a Visualforce page? It doesn't seem to be an Apex class

Comment: @AlbaRivas It's actually Apex Class. I am basically constructing a body of email that I want to send and this is a part of that body. I want that recipients should be able to click on the link and it should redirect them to that record.

Comment: But then you'd have to concatenate the HTML code with the variables computed by Apex, wouldn't you? Doing something like.... "<a href='" + system.getbase.... + "' > Click Here </a>". Maybe you can edit your question and add a bit more of your Apex class content.

Comment: @AlbaRivas I have added the whole body that I am trying to construct. Will that suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some quotes. Try this:

```
String htmlBody = '<b>Notification:</b></br></br>The Offer has been Approved at Stage'
                  + app.Stage__c
                  + '</br></br><b>Main-Offer Name: </b>'
                  + app.Main_Offer_Name__r.Name
                  + '</br></br><b>Offer Link: </b><a href="' + System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()
                  + '/'
                  + app.Main_Offer_Name__c
                  + '"> Click Here</a></br></br>';
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I just added toExternalForm() at the end to System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() and that solved my issue.